# php: is valid to use if/else in this way?

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there a way to optimize something like this? 
I have already tried and it doesn't work (at least in php)

```
$foo = 6;
if ($foo != (3 or 5 or 10)) echo "it work";
elseif($foo < (5 or 10)) echo "it work again";
else echo "it doesn't work;"
```

I want to know if there's a better way to write that kind of validations.
But if something like this work in other langs, please let me know.

---

EDIT: 
answer for this

```
($foo != (3 or 5 or 10)) -> in_array($foo,array(3,5,10))
```

does the same work if i want something like

```
($foo != (3 and 5 and 10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's not. You're testing your `$foo` value against the BOOLEAN result of those `or` operations. It'll boil down to

```
if ($foo != (true or true or true))
```

which is simply

```
if ($foo != true)
if (!$foo)
```

If you want to test a single value against multiple values, you can try

```
if(!in_array($foo, array(3,5,10))) { ... }
```

instead. For your `<` version, this won't work. You'll have to test each value individually:

```
if (($foo < 5) or ($foo < 10)) { ... }
```

though technically this is somewhat redundant, since if $foo is less than 5, it's already less than 10.

Comment: +1 This is an excellent answer but I think the real issue that needs to be addressed is the fact that micro-optimization is 99% not worth the effort and makes code illegible for future reading.

Answer (score 0):

For the first you can use

```
if(!in_array($foo, [5,10,15]))
```

The second thing doesn't work in any language cause less then 5 or 10 is true for every thing less than 10. So no need for the 5. But I get your point. I don't know a fast way doing this

In python you can do this:

```
if(5 < x < 10)
    a, b = b, a // swapping these two
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers and also, if you have more processing to do, you could also do something like this:

```
<?php

$x = 3;

switch ($x)
{
    case 6:
        $x = 5;
    case 3:
    case 7:
        $x = 5;
    case 5:
        echo 'It is working' . PHP_EOL;
        break;
}
```

**EDIT**: Thanks DanFromGermany for pointing the stacked cases. Added them as an example.

Comment: You forgot the `break;`s

Comment: No, I did not. Why would you exit the loop before doing your job?

Comment: No need for breaks if you don't want them!

Comment: or stack the cases: `case 6: case 3: $x = 5;`

Comment: @FlorinAsavoaie - without the `break;` the first and second cases will both run if `$x == 6`.  In this case, it doesn't matter because they do the same thing, but can be a dangerous mistake.